# Python - Killing more than one thread on Control+C

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong ?

I simply need to kill both threads on Control+C.

```
def cleanup_stop_thread():
    for thread in enumerate():
        if thread.isAlive():
            try:
                self._Thread__stop()
            except:
                print(str(thread.getName()) + ' could not be terminated')

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    try:
        threading.Thread(target = record).start()
        threading.Thread(target = ftp).start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanup_stop_thread();
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: what's the message the you are getting?

Comment: If you're trying to catch the term signal (ctrl+c) I recommend you use the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module.

Comment: `self._Thread__stop()` here you are stopping the current thread. replace that with `thread._Thread__stop()`

Comment: @Michael That shouldn't be needed. Catching the KeyboardInterrupt exception is the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to kill them on Ctrl+C, why don't you just make them daemon threads? Then they exit automatically when the main thread dies.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=record)
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=ftp)
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()
```

Comment: This is really a simple solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to kill all threads when typing CTRL+C just add a try block and import os
and do os._exit(0) when you want to kill everything
also check the atexit module

Hope it helped :)